# why and when to use torch.cuda.Stream()

Tags: pytorch

I found `torch.cuda.Stream()` is manually defined in some open source code.

```
    self.input_stream = torch.cuda.Stream()
    self.model_stream = torch.cuda.Stream()
    self.output_stream = torch.cuda.Stream()
```

On [torch page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html/), it says

`You normally do not need to create one explicitly: by default, each device uses its own “default” stream.`

Trying to understand why they *had to* define this manually. From the quick google search, there are lots of **how** to use `cuda.Stream()` but no **why/when/best-practice** to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Streams are sequences of cuda kernels. Operations in different streams may run in parallel. I don't believe they *have* to use them. They are are just making the code *more parallel* and thus hopefully faster.

Answer (score 0):

I read in a StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498690/how-to-use-cuda-stream-in-pytorch) regarding it. Though it is also `how` to use.
But after reading it, all I got is:

- `Why`/`When` use stream: To parallelize some computations.
- `Best Practices` to use the stream: To boost up some really extensive computational tasks through parallelizing. *(Mostly; you are welcome to comment if any better answer is found.)*

Reference:

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-semantics

Comment: Where did you get the information that torch allows only 2 streams? Even the code in the question contains 3. If I use 8 GPUs I definitely use at least 8 streams.

Comment: I might be wrong here since I don't have access to more GPUs. And since it is a piece of very limited knowledge. so I am removing that sentence. Thanks for pointing it out.